# COUNTDOWNTIMER onfinish(); still called after cancel

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I want to cancel the onfinish function of countdountimer when a button is clicked i do timer.cancel but on finish is still called.

```
            running = false;
            countDownTimer.cancel();
            countDownTimer = null;  
            finish();
            startActivity(i);
```

and this is the countdowntimer

```
private CountDownTimer createTimer() {
    return new CountDownTimer(getIntent().getIntExtra("timer", 5460000),
            1000) {

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            timer.setText("Section time: "
                    + String.format(
                            Locale.ENGLISH,
                            "%d min, %d sec",
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                                    .toMinutes(millisUntilFinished),
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                                    .toSeconds(millisUntilFinished)
                                    - TimeUnit.MINUTES
                                            .toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                                                    .toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));
            timer_count = (int) millisUntilFinished;
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            if (running) {
                int random;
                if (getIntent().getIntExtra("t_no", 0) < 20) {
                    i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            Practice_intruction.class);
                    i.putExtra("type", "Test");
                    Random r = new Random();
                    random = r.nextInt(MainActivity.vocab.size() - 11);
                    i.putExtra("q_no", random);
                    i.putExtra("t_no", 20);
                    i.putExtra("answers",
                            getIntent().getStringExtra("answers"));
                    countDownTimer.cancel();
                    countDownTimer = null;
                    running = false;
                    finish();
                    startActivity(i);
                } else if (getIntent().getIntExtra("t_no", 0) < 40) {
                    i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            Practice_intruction.class);
                    i.putExtra("type", "Test");
                    Random r = new Random();
                    random = r.nextInt(MainActivity.listining.size() - 4);
                    i.putExtra("q_no", random);
                    i.putExtra("t_no", 40);
                    i.putExtra("answers",
                            getIntent().getStringExtra("answers"));
                    countDownTimer.cancel();
                    countDownTimer = null;
                    running = false;
                    finish();
                    startActivity(i);

                } else if (getIntent().getIntExtra("t_no", 0) < 50) {
                    i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            Practice_intruction.class);
                    i.putExtra("type", "Test");
                    Random r = new Random();
                    random = r.nextInt(MainActivity.reading.size() - 1);
                    i.putExtra("paragraph_id", random + 1);
                    i.putExtra("q_no", 0);
                    i.putExtra("t_no", 50);
                    i.putExtra("answers",
                            getIntent().getStringExtra("answers"));
                    countDownTimer.cancel();
                    countDownTimer = null;
                    running = false;
                    finish();
                    startActivity(i);
                } else if (getIntent().getIntExtra("t_no", 0) < 60) {
                    i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            Practice_intruction.class);
                    i.putExtra("type", "Test");
                    Random r = new Random();
                    random = r.nextInt(MainActivity.vid.size() - 1);
                    i.putExtra("Scene_ID", random + 1);
                    i.putExtra("q_no", 0);
                    i.putExtra("t_no", 60);
                    i.putExtra("answers",
                            getIntent().getStringExtra("answers"));
                    countDownTimer.cancel();
                    countDownTimer = null;
                    running = false;
                    finish();
                    startActivity(i);
                } else if (getIntent().getIntExtra("t_no", 0) < 100) {
                    i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            Practice_result.class);
                    i.putExtra("type", getIntent().getStringExtra("type"));
                    i.putExtra("answers",
                            getIntent().getStringExtra("answers"));
                    countDownTimer.cancel();
                    countDownTimer = null;
                    running = false;
                    finish();
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }

        }

    }.start();
}
```

this is a part of my activity where i am using the countdowntimer, i am not using it anywhere exept here

```
else if (getIntent().getStringExtra("type").equalsIgnoreCase("Test")) {

        timer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        back.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        running = true;

        countDownTimer = this.createTimer();

        if (getIntent().getIntExtra("t_no", 0) < 10) {

            final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> questions = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                if (MainActivity.structure.get(i).get("type_p_t")
                        .equalsIgnoreCase("t"))
                    questions.add(MainActivity.structure.get(i));
            }
            main_txt.setText("Q"
                    + (getIntent().getIntExtra("t_no", 0) + 1)
                    + ": "
                    + questions.get(getIntent().getIntExtra("q_no", 0))
                            .get("question").replace("#", ""));
            title.setText("Structure/ Sentence Completion");
            opt_a_txt.setText(questions
                    .get(getIntent().getIntExtra("q_no", 0)).get("choices")
                    .split("#")[0]);
            opt_b_txt.setText(questions
                    .get(getIntent().getIntExtra("q_no", 0)).get("choices")
                    .split("#")[1]);
            opt_c_txt.setText(questions
                    .get(getIntent().getIntExtra("q_no", 0)).get("choices")
                    .split("#")[2]);
            opt_d_txt.setText(questions
                    .get(getIntent().getIntExtra("q_no", 0)).get("choices")
                    .split("#")[3]);
            cor_ans = questions.get(getIntent().getIntExtra("q_no", 0))
                    .get("cor_ans");
            next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    int random;
                    if (getIntent().getIntExtra("t_no", 0) == 9) {
                        i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                Practice_intruction.class);
                        i.putExtra("type", "Test");
                        Random r = new Random();
                        random = r.nextInt(MainActivity.structure.size() - 51);
                    } else {
                        i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                Struct.class);
                        i.putExtra("type",
                                getIntent().getStringExtra("type"));
                        Random r = new Random();
                        random = r.nextInt(MainActivity.structure.size() - 51);
                        while (Helper.sec_questions.contains(random)) {
                            random = r.nextInt(MainActivity.structure
                                    .size() - 51);
                        }
                        Helper.sec_questions.add(random);

                    }
                    i.putExtra("q_no", random);
                    i.putExtra("t_no",
                            getIntent().getIntExtra("t_no", 0) + 1);
                    if (ans.equalsIgnoreCase(cor_ans)) {
                        i.putExtra("answers",
                                getIntent().getStringExtra("answers")
                                        + "true#");

                    } else {
                        i.putExtra("answers",
                                getIntent().getStringExtra("answers")
                                        + "false#");
                    }

                    i.putExtra("timer", timer_count);

                    Details_data.answers.add(ans);
                    Details_data.choices.add(opt_a_txt.getText().toString()
                            + "#" + opt_b_txt.getText().toString() + "#"
                            + opt_c_txt.getText().toString() + "#"
                            + opt_d_txt.getText().toString());
                    Details_data.correct_answers.add(cor_ans);
                    Details_data.questions.add(main_txt.getText()
                            .toString());
                    Details_data.why.add(questions
                            .get(getIntent().getIntExtra("q_no", 0))
                            .get("why").replace("#", ""));

                    running = false;
                    countDownTimer.cancel();
                    countDownTimer.onFinish();
                    countDownTimer = null;

                    finish();
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });

        } else if (getIntent().getIntExtra("t_no", 0) < 20) {

            final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> questions = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            for (int i = 50; i < MainActivity.structure.size(); i++) {
                if (MainActivity.structure.get(i).get("type_p_t")
                        .equalsIgnoreCase("t"))
                    questions.add(MainActivity.structure.get(i));
            }
            main_txt.setText("Q"
                    + (getIntent().getIntExtra("t_no", 0) + 1)
                    + ": "
                    + questions.get(getIntent().getIntExtra("q_no", 0))
                            .get("question").replace("#", ""));
            title.setText("Structure/ Error Identification");
            opt_a_txt.setText(questions
                    .get(getIntent().getIntExtra("q_no", 0)).get("choices")
                    .split("#")[0]);
            opt_b_txt.setText(questions
                    .get(getIntent().getIntExtra("q_no", 0)).get("choices")
                    .split("#")[1]);
            opt_c_txt.setText(questions
                    .get(getIntent().getIntExtra("q_no", 0)).get("choices")
                    .split("#")[2]);
            opt_d_txt.setText(questions
                    .get(getIntent().getIntExtra("q_no", 0)).get("choices")
                    .split("#")[3]);
            cor_ans = questions.get(getIntent().getIntExtra("q_no", 0))
                    .get("cor_ans");
            next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    int random;
                    if (getIntent().getIntExtra("t_no", 0) == 19) {
                        i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                Practice_intruction.class);
                        i.putExtra("type", "Test");
                        Random r = new Random();
                        random = r.nextInt(MainActivity.vocab.size() - 11);
                    } else {
                        i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                Struct.class);
                        i.putExtra("type",
                                getIntent().getStringExtra("type"));
                        Random r = new Random();
                        random = r.nextInt(MainActivity.structure.size() - 51);
                        while (Helper.sec_questions.contains(random)) {
                            random = r.nextInt(MainActivity.structure
                                    .size() - 51);
                        }
                        Helper.sec_questions.add(random);
                    }
                    i.putExtra("q_no", random);
                    i.putExtra("t_no",
                            getIntent().getIntExtra("t_no", 0) + 1);
                    if (ans.equalsIgnoreCase(cor_ans)) {
                        i.putExtra("answers",
                                getIntent().getStringExtra("answers")
                                        + "true#");

                    } else {
                        i.putExtra("answers",
                                getIntent().getStringExtra("answers")
                                        + "false#");
                    }

                    i.putExtra("timer", timer_count);

                    Details_data.answers.add(ans);
                    Details_data.choices.add(opt_a_txt.getText().toString()
                            + "#" + opt_b_txt.getText().toString() + "#"
                            + opt_c_txt.getText().toString() + "#"
                            + opt_d_txt.getText().toString());
                    Details_data.correct_answers.add(cor_ans);
                    Details_data.questions.add(main_txt.getText()
                            .toString());
                    Details_data.why.add(questions
                            .get(getIntent().getIntExtra("q_no", 0))
                            .get("why").replace("#", ""));

                    running = false;
                    countDownTimer.cancel();
                    countDownTimer.onFinish();
                    countDownTimer = null;

                    finish();
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });

        } else if (getIntent().getIntExtra("t_no", 0) < 40) {

            final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> questions = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            for (int i = 0; i < MainActivity.vocab.size(); i++) {
                if (MainActivity.vocab.get(i).get("type_p_t")
                        .equalsIgnoreCase("t"))
                    questions.add(MainActivity.vocab.get(i));
            }
            main_txt.setText("Q"
                    + (getIntent().getIntExtra("t_no", 0) + 1)
                    + ": "
                    + questions.get(getIntent().getIntExtra("q_no", 0))
                            .get("question").replace("#", ""));
            title.setText("Vocabulary");
            opt_a_txt.setText(questions
                    .get(getIntent().getIntExtra("q_no", 0)).get("choices")
                    .split("#")[0]);
            opt_b_txt.setText(questions
                    .get(getIntent().getIntExtra("q_no", 0)).get("choices")
                    .split("#")[1]);
            opt_c_txt.setText(questions
                    .get(getIntent().getIntExtra("q_no", 0)).get("choices")
                    .split("#")[2]);
            opt_d_txt.setText(questions
                    .get(getIntent().getIntExtra("q_no", 0)).get("choices")
                    .split("#")[3]);
            cor_ans = questions.get(getIntent().getIntExtra("q_no", 0))
                    .get("cor_ans");
            next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    int random;
                    if (getIntent().getIntExtra("t_no", 0) == 39) {
                        i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                Practice_intruction.class);
                        i.putExtra("type", "Test");
                        Random r = new Random();
                        random = r.nextInt(MainActivity.listining.size() - 4);
                    } else {
                        i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                Struct.class);
                        i.putExtra("type",
                                getIntent().getStringExtra("type"));
                        Random r = new Random();
                        random = r.nextInt(MainActivity.vocab.size() - 11);
                        while (Helper.sec_questions.contains(random)) {
                            random = r.nextInt(MainActivity.vocab.size() - 11);
                        }
                        Helper.sec_questions.add(random);
                    }
                    i.putExtra("q_no", random);
                    i.putExtra("t_no",
                            getIntent().getIntExtra("t_no", 0) + 1);
                    if (ans.equalsIgnoreCase(cor_ans)) {
                        i.putExtra("answers",
                                getIntent().getStringExtra("answers")
                                        + "true#");

                    } else {
                        i.putExtra("answers",
                                getIntent().getStringExtra("answers")
                                        + "false#");
                    }

                    i.putExtra("timer", timer_count);

                    Details_data.answers.add(ans);
                    Details_data.choices.add(opt_a_txt.getText().toString()
                            + "#" + opt_b_txt.getText().toString() + "#"
                            + opt_c_txt.getText().toString() + "#"
                            + opt_d_txt.getText().toString());
                    Details_data.correct_answers.add(cor_ans);
                    Details_data.questions.add(main_txt.getText()
                            .toString());

                    running = false;
                    countDownTimer.cancel();
                    countDownTimer.onFinish();
                    countDownTimer = null;

                    finish();
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
        } else if (getIntent().getIntExtra("t_no", 0) < 50) {
            final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> questions = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            main_txt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            opt_a.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            opt_b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            opt_c.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            opt_d.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            headset.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            for (int i = 0; i < MainActivity.listining.size(); i++) {
                if (MainActivity.listining.get(i).get("type_p_t")
                        .equalsIgnoreCase("t"))
                    questions.add(MainActivity.listining.get(i));
            }
            main_txt.setText("Q"
                    + (getIntent().getIntExtra("t_no", 0) + 1)
                    + ": "
                    + questions.get(getIntent().getIntExtra("q_no", 0))
                            .get("question").replace("#", ""));
            title.setText("Listening Comprehension");
            opt_a_txt.setText(questions
                    .get(getIntent().getIntExtra("q_no", 0)).get("choices")
                    .split("#")[0]);
            opt_b_txt.setText(questions
                    .get(getIntent().getIntExtra("q_no", 0)).get("choices")
                    .split("#")[1]);
            opt_c_txt.setText(questions
                    .get(getIntent().getIntExtra("q_no", 0)).get("choices")
                    .split("#")[2]);
            opt_d_txt.setText(questions
                    .get(getIntent().getIntExtra("q_no", 0)).get("choices")
                    .split("#")[3]);
            cor_ans = questions.get(getIntent().getIntExtra("q_no", 0))
                    .get("cor_ans");
            next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    int random;
                    if (getIntent().getIntExtra("t_no", 0) == 49) {
                        i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                Practice_intruction.class);
                        i.putExtra("type",
                                getIntent().getStringExtra("type"));
                        Random r = new Random();
                        random = r.nextInt(MainActivity.reading.size() - 1);
                        i.putExtra("paragraph_id", random + 1);
                        i.putExtra("q_no", 0);
                    } else {
                        i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                Struct.class);
                        i.putExtra("type",
                                getIntent().getStringExtra("type"));
                        Random r = new Random();
                        random = r.nextInt(MainActivity.listining.size() - 4);
                        while (Helper.sec_questions.contains(random)) {
                            random = r.nextInt(MainActivity.listining
                                    .size() - 4);
                        }
                        Helper.sec_questions.add(random);
                        i.putExtra("q_no", random);
                    }
                    i.putExtra("t_no",
                            getIntent().getIntExtra("t_no", 0) + 1);
                    if (ans.equalsIgnoreCase(cor_ans)) {
                        i.putExtra("answers",
                                getIntent().getStringExtra("answers")
                                        + "true#");

                    } else {
                        i.putExtra("answers",
                                getIntent().getStringExtra("answers")
                                        + "false#");
                    }

                    i.putExtra("timer", timer_count);

                    Details_data.answers.add(ans);
                    Details_data.choices.add(opt_a_txt.getText().toString()
                            + "#" + opt_b_txt.getText().toString() + "#"
                            + opt_c_txt.getText().toString() + "#"
                            + opt_d_txt.getText().toString());
                    Details_data.correct_answers.add(cor_ans);
                    Details_data.questions.add(main_txt.getText()
                            .toString());

                    running = false;
                    countDownTimer.cancel();
                    countDownTimer.onFinish();
                    countDownTimer = null;

                    finish();
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });

            listen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mp = new MediaPlayer();
            listen.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    try {
                        mp.setDataSource("/mnt/sdcard/qualification/"
                                + questions.get(
                                        getIntent().getIntExtra("q_no", 0))
                                        .get("voice") + ".mp3");
                        mp.prepare();
                        mp.start();
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (SecurityException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    listen.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }
            });

            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.release();
                    mp = null;
                    main_txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    opt_a.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    opt_b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    opt_c.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    opt_d.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    headset.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
        } else if (getIntent().getIntExtra("t_no", 0) < 60) {
            paragraph.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> questions = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            for (int i = 0; i < MainActivity.reading_qst.size(); i++) {
                if (MainActivity.reading_qst
                        .get(i)
                        .get("paragraph_id")
                        .equalsIgnoreCase(
                                String.valueOf(getIntent().getIntExtra(
                                        "paragraph_id", 0) + 1)))
                    questions.add(MainActivity.reading_qst.get(i));
            }
            main_txt.setText("Q"
                    + (getIntent().getIntExtra("t_no", 0) + 1)
                    + ": "
                    + questions.get(getIntent().getIntExtra("q_no", 0))
                            .get("question").replace("#", ""));
            title.setText("Reading Comprehension");
            opt_a_txt.setText(questions
                    .get(getIntent().getIntExtra("q_no", 0)).get("choices")
                    .split("#")[0]);
            opt_b_txt.setText(questions
                    .get(getIntent().getIntExtra("q_no", 0)).get("choices")
                    .split("#")[1]);
            opt_c_txt.setText(questions
                    .get(getIntent().getIntExtra("q_no", 0)).get("choices")
                    .split("#")[2]);
            opt_d_txt.setText(questions
                    .get(getIntent().getIntExtra("q_no", 0)).get("choices")
                    .split("#")[3]);
            cor_ans = questions.get(getIntent().getIntExtra("q_no", 0))
                    .get("cor_ans");
            next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int random;
                    if (getIntent().getIntExtra("t_no", 0) == 59) {
                        i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                Practice_intruction.class);
                        i.putExtra("type", "Test");
                        Random r = new Random();
                        random = r.nextInt(MainActivity.vid.size() - 1);
                        i.putExtra("Scene_ID", random + 1);
                        i.putExtra("q_no", 0);
                    } else if (getIntent().getIntExtra("t_no", 0) == 54) {
                        i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                Reading.class);
                        i.putExtra("type", "Test");
                        Random r = new Random();
                        random = r.nextInt(MainActivity.reading.size() - 1);
                        while (Helper.sec_questions.contains(random)) {
                            random = r.nextInt(MainActivity.reading.size() - 2);
                        }
                        Helper.sec_questions.add(random + 1);
                        i.putExtra("paragraph_id", random + 1);
                        i.putExtra("q_no", 0);
                    } else {
                        i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                Struct.class);
                        i.putExtra("type",
                                getIntent().getStringExtra("type"));
                        i.putExtra("paragraph_id",
                                getIntent().getIntExtra("paragraph_id", 0));
                        i.putExtra("q_no",
                                getIntent().getIntExtra("q_no", 0) + 1);
                    }
                    i.putExtra("t_no",
                            getIntent().getIntExtra("t_no", 0) + 1);
                    if (ans.equalsIgnoreCase(cor_ans)) {
                        i.putExtra("answers",
                                getIntent().getStringExtra("answers")
                                        + "true#");
                    } else {
                        i.putExtra("answers",
                                getIntent().getStringExtra("answers")
                                        + "false#");
                    }
                    i.putExtra("timer", timer_count);

                    Details_data.answers.add(ans);
                    Details_data.choices.add(opt_a_txt.getText().toString()
                            + "#" + opt_b_txt.getText().toString() + "#"
                            + opt_c_txt.getText().toString() + "#"
                            + opt_d_txt.getText().toString());
                    Details_data.correct_answers.add(cor_ans);
                    Details_data.questions.add(main_txt.getText()
                            .toString());

                    running = false;
                    countDownTimer.cancel();
                    countDownTimer.onFinish();
                    countDownTimer = null;

                    finish();
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
        }

        else if (getIntent().getIntExtra("t_no", 0) < 100) {
            final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> questions = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            for (int i = 0; i < MainActivity.vid_qst.size(); i++) {
                if (MainActivity.vid_qst
                        .get(i)
                        .get("Scene_ID")
                        .equalsIgnoreCase(
                                String.valueOf(getIntent().getIntExtra(
                                        "Scene_ID", 0) + 1)))
                    questions.add(MainActivity.vid_qst.get(i));
            }
            main_txt.setText("Q"
                    + (getIntent().getIntExtra("t_no", 0) + 1)
                    + ": "
                    + questions.get(getIntent().getIntExtra("q_no", 0))
                            .get("question").replace("#", ""));
            title.setText("Visual Comprehension");
            opt_a_txt.setText(questions
                    .get(getIntent().getIntExtra("q_no", 0)).get("choices")
                    .split("#")[0]);
            opt_b_txt.setText(questions
                    .get(getIntent().getIntExtra("q_no", 0)).get("choices")
                    .split("#")[1]);
            opt_c_txt.setText(questions
                    .get(getIntent().getIntExtra("q_no", 0)).get("choices")
                    .split("#")[2]);
            opt_d_txt.setText(questions
                    .get(getIntent().getIntExtra("q_no", 0)).get("choices")
                    .split("#")[3]);
            cor_ans = questions.get(getIntent().getIntExtra("q_no", 0))
                    .get("cor_ans");
            next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (getIntent().getIntExtra("t_no", 0) == 99) {
                        i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                Practice_result.class);
                        i.putExtra("type",
                                getIntent().getStringExtra("type"));
                    } else if (getIntent().getIntExtra("t_no", 0) == 59
                            || getIntent().getIntExtra("t_no", 0) == 69
                            || getIntent().getIntExtra("t_no", 0) == 79
                            || getIntent().getIntExtra("t_no", 0) == 89) {
                        i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Video.class);
                        i.putExtra("type", "Test");
                        Random r = new Random();
                        int random = r.nextInt(MainActivity.vid.size() - 1);
                        while (Helper.sec_questions.contains(random)) {
                            random = r.nextInt(MainActivity.vid.size() - 1);
                        }
                        Helper.sec_questions.add(random + 1);
                        i.putExtra("Scene_ID", random + 1);
                        i.putExtra("q_no", 0);
                    } else {
                        i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                Struct.class);
                        i.putExtra("type",
                                getIntent().getStringExtra("type"));
                        i.putExtra("q_no",
                                getIntent().getIntExtra("q_no", 0) + 1);
                        i.putExtra("Scene_ID",
                                getIntent().getIntExtra("Scene_ID", 0));
                    }
                    i.putExtra("t_no",
                            getIntent().getIntExtra("t_no", 0) + 1);
                    if (ans.equalsIgnoreCase(cor_ans)) {
                        i.putExtra("answers",
                                getIntent().getStringExtra("answers")
                                        + "true#");
                    } else {
                        i.putExtra("answers",
                                getIntent().getStringExtra("answers")
                                        + "false#");
                    }
                    i.putExtra("timer", timer_count);

                    Details_data.answers.add(ans);
                    Details_data.choices.add(opt_a_txt.getText().toString()
                            + "#" + opt_b_txt.getText().toString() + "#"
                            + opt_c_txt.getText().toString() + "#"
                            + opt_d_txt.getText().toString());
                    Details_data.correct_answers.add(cor_ans);
                    Details_data.questions.add(main_txt.getText()
                            .toString());

                    running = false;
                    countDownTimer.cancel();
                    countDownTimer.onFinish();
                    countDownTimer = null;

                    finish();
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
        }

    }

    opt_a.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            opt_a_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ans_sel_yallow);
            opt_b_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ans_sel_white);
            opt_c_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ans_sel_white);
            opt_d_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ans_sel_white);

            ans = "a";

            next.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            paragraph.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    });

    opt_b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            opt_a_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ans_sel_white);
            opt_b_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ans_sel_yallow);
            opt_c_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ans_sel_white);
            opt_d_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ans_sel_white);

            ans = "b";

            next.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            paragraph.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

    opt_c.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            opt_a_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ans_sel_white);
            opt_b_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ans_sel_white);
            opt_c_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ans_sel_yallow);
            opt_d_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ans_sel_white);

            ans = "c";

            next.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            paragraph.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

    opt_d.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            opt_a_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ans_sel_white);
            opt_b_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ans_sel_white);
            opt_c_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ans_sel_white);
            opt_d_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ans_sel_yallow);

            ans = "d";

            next.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            paragraph.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

    back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Struct.this)
                    .create();

            if (alert != null) {
                alert.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?!");
                alert.setCancelable(true);
                alert.setButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                Intent i = new Intent(
                                        getApplicationContext(),
                                        MainMenu.class);
                                running = false;
                                if (countDownTimer != null) {
                                    countDownTimer.cancel();
                                    countDownTimer.onFinish();
                                    countDownTimer = null;
                                }

                                finish();
                                startActivity(i);
                            }
                        });
                alert.setButton2("No",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {

                            }
                        });
                alert.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

                alert.show();
                TextView msg = (TextView) alert
                        .findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                if (msg != null)
                    msg.setTextSize(20);

                Button b1 = (Button) alert
                        .findViewById(android.R.id.button1);
                if (b1 != null)
                    b1.setTextSize(20);

                Button b2 = (Button) alert
                        .findViewById(android.R.id.button2);
                if (b2 != null)
                    b2.setTextSize(20);

            }

        }
    });

    paragraph.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Reading.class);
            i.putExtra("type", getIntent().getStringExtra("type"));
            i.putExtra("paragraph_id",
                    getIntent().getIntExtra("paragraph_id", 0));
            i.putExtra("q_no", getIntent().getIntExtra("q_no", 0));
            i.putExtra("t_no", getIntent().getIntExtra("t_no", 0));
            i.putExtra("answers", getIntent().getStringExtra("answers"));
            i.putExtra("timer", timer_count);
            i.putExtra("return", true);

            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: onFinish will ever be called if you cancel the timer. There is no way to avoid this...

Comment: no i have tried it so many times but it is still called after a while.

Comment: set your boolean `running` to false BEFORE countDownTimer.cancel();

Comment: i did it but the problem still the same

Comment: that´s impossible, I guess you have overlooked something. Ok, what we need now is, please post where you are starting the counter, finish the counter. Everywhere you have used the countdowntimer, please post it here. Maybe there is anywhere a call where you haven´t set the running to false....

Comment: and whya you have not the @Override annotation at your onFinish() method?

Comment: you are calling `countDownTimer.onFinish();` extra after you call `cancel()`...delete this line...

Comment: i added this line recently .

Comment: i didn't have it before and the problem was happening

Comment: sorry, I don´t think its the problem, but also, don´t call it. The countdowntimer does it by himself, no need to call it...

Comment: and I´m still confused about your post. Could you please update ALL YOU HAVE POSTED HERE? inside the countdowntimer code itself in the first post, there is still `running=false` after cancel.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs i updated it

Comment: ok, and now, step by step: Are you running these if/else statements inside your onFinish() method also a second time anywhere else or why is it similar to your last post?

Comment: it's close but not similar, the if/else statements are complicated. please just take a look at where i am using countdowntimer. BTW: thanks for your patience.

Comment: I make some suggestion. Send me your project, so I can see everything. Can you upload it anywhere link me to your project like for example to dropbox or google drive?

Comment: i am sorry but the app belongs to the company i work in.

Comment: ok, but from the posted code, I can´t help. I tried but I guess, there is anywhere in your code wether a running=true in confrontation with your countdownTimer, or, what is also possible, you have created multiple timers that have not been cancled.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs and that is the problem. i checked my code a thousand times and i am using countdowntimer only one time that is canceled everytime

Comment: sometimes you doesn´t see the tree in the woods, believe me I stumpled often into this :). May the countdowntimer starts in one of your started activities again. So what You can do to be sure is, If your countDownTimer is an extra class, right click in your project structure on CountDownTimer and select "FindUsages". The all usages get listed in the process window in Android Studio and you can check all.

Comment: There must be any issue, because if the boolean `running` would be really false at this time, the code in the onFinish() will definetely not be executed.....

Comment: Maybe I´ve seen something, but I am not sure. In Your class `createTimer()`, you are returning a `CountDownTimer` BUT you also start the timer in that method. I think you are returning a `CountDownTimer Objekt`, that is allready started, but I don´t think that this a good practise. You should start the returned objekt. Please try the following: remove the `start()` call from your `createTimer()` class and start the timer on your new object like:  `countDownTimer = this.createTimer(); and then countDownTimer.start();`

Comment: maybe this practise occurs a competitor to your countDownTimer object...

Answer (score 2):

Seems that finish() is called in any case. However, if you set running to false before cancelling, your finish() method does nothing, so it should be okay.

```
running = false;
countdownTimer.cancel();
```

Comment: i set running to false but it is still concedered as true.

Comment: Did you set it to false before calling cancel?

Comment: but you have to set it to false BEFORE you call cancel(). On every place you call cancel()....

Answer (score 0):

Note that in the code snippet you are trying to cancel the timer in the onFinish() method. That is not required, nor does it have any sort of effect on the timer.

Also, place a call to `Log.v("SomeTag", "onFinish() called");` on top of `onFinish()` and a call to `Log.v("SomeTag", "OnClick() called");` on top of `onClick()` and check logcat for the output. Are you absolutely certain that `onFinish()` and `onClick()` are actually called and what you are seeing is not a side effect of some other code? Note that `finish();` does not immediately finish the activity, but only after the current method being executed returns.

Comment: place a call to Log.v("SomeTag", "onFinish() called"); on the top of onFinish(). Are you absolutely certain that onFinish is actually called and what you are seeing is not a sideffect of some other code? Note that finish(); does not immediately finish the activity, but only after the current method beeing executed returns.

Comment: yes i am sure that on finish is called after the countdowntimer millisec reach 0 even if i cancel it

Comment: Maybe show us the EXACT code in onClick()? Also, you don't need to set the timer to null to cancel it (at least you shouldn't).

Answer (score 0):

I've made my own CountDownTimer based on @Ridcully answer :

```
public abstract class CustomCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {

public boolean running;

public CustomCountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
    super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    running = true;
}

@Override
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    tick(millisUntilFinished);
}

@Override
public void onFinish() {
    if(running) {
        finish();
    }
}

public abstract void finish();
public abstract void tick(long millisUntilFinished);

public void stop(){
    running = false;
    cancel();
}

}
```

You should now call stop() instead of cancel()